# How to use defined color from App.xaml in Android style in xamarin forms

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms

I have color defined in app.xaml

```
 <Color x:Key="AppPrimaryColor">#FF9515</Color>
```

Is where way to use this color in android/Resources/style.xml 
For example:

```
<style name="MainTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">

<item name="colorPrimary">AppPrimaryColor</item>
```

Comment: Check this thread: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/87257/can-we-override-android-values-styles-xml-in-app-xaml

Comment: @EvZ Thanks but not exactly what i wanted

Answer (score 0):

See  [Resources and Styles in Xamarin.Forms (XAM140)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wgc3M5WwOlk)

Comment: The link is dead.  Could you provide more content?

Comment: seems like the older courses are being archived. Although it still seems relevant enough.
The youtube version is still there..   I updated the link.